# Change login name when name is with domain and dot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with renaming user name to new username (I would like it to be shorter).

Original syntax should be like this:

```
ALTER LOGIN Mary5 WITH NAME = John2;
```

But my user has name like this: domain/name.lastname and sql server is giving me error, trying to execute this:

```
ALTER LOGIN mydomain\fname.lstname WITH NAME = shortername
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near '\'.

I've tried to put both names in single quotes, which drops another syntax error. How to rename that user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would specify the user with brackets like below. But apparently you cannot remove the domain from a user once it's been created with one. You must delete and recreate the user.

```
ALTER LOGIN [mydomain\fname.lstname] WITH NAME = [shortername]
```

When specifying a different domain user you will receive the following error: "The name change cannot be performed because the SID of the new name does not match the old SID of the principal.". Further suggesting you cannot simply alter a login based on a domain user.

Comment: Error: Invalid value given for parameter NAME. Specify a valid parameter value. Is this working for you?

Comment: @FrenkyB What value are you specifying?

Comment: Just like query above is written.

Comment: @FrenkyB Can you try with brackets? [mydomain\flname.lstname]?

Comment: @FrenkyB I just tested it, apparently you cannot remove the domain. You must specify it again. Looks like you will have to remove your user and recreate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168288/discussion-between-frenkyb-and-bdebaere).